# List/Array member can't be addressed - Euler 14

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have the below code. I create a list (tried with array as well) with one million and one members. All of them has the value 0 by default. It should work like a multidimensional array, but it's not necessary as the first 'column' has to be numbers from 1-1.000.000. To make life easier I made 1.000.001 members to avoid using the 0th place.
At a certain point I have to use a member of this list addressed by a variable: list[n], and to avoid issues this only happens if n < 1.000.000. As there are members from 0-1.000.000 I think it's OK, but still my program crashes after a while with error code ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
What am I missing here?

```
            int highestCount = 0;
            int highestNum = 0;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            for(int j = 0; j <= 1000001; j++)
            {
                list.Add(0);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                int count = 0;
                int number = i;
                do
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        number = number / 2;
                        if (number < 1000000)
                        {
                            if (list[number] != 0)
                            {
                                count += list[number];
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        else { count++; };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        number = (number * 3) + 1;
                        if (number < 1000000)
                        {
                            if (list[number] != 0) //program dies here
                                {
                                    count += list[number];
                                    break;
                                }
                            else
                            {
                             count++;
                            }
                        }
                        else { count++; };

                    }
                } while (number > 1);
                list[i] = count;
                if (count > highestCount)
                {
                    highestCount = count;
                    highestNum = i;
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show(highestNum.ToString());
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find the index.

Comment: 100663842, which shouldn't be examined

Comment: _To make life easier_ you should get used to the `0..n-1` pattern quickly.

Comment: Yes you are. It is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a problem with your logic.

When i == 3 (on the second run), it will go into the do-while block.
Since i % 2 != 0 at that point, it will hit the else.
The number is multiplied by 3 and you add 1.
It is less than 1000000, but....

```
if(list[number] != 0)
```

never evaluates to true and you are stuck in an infinite do-while loop and it never breaks out because A) number will always be greater than 1 (satisfying the while condition); and B) you set every element of the array to zero in the code above this loop (thus never satisfying the above if condition):

```
for(int j = 0; j <= 1000001; j++)
{
    list.Add(0);
}
```

Comment: It has 1.000.001. But still.

Comment: Check closely, I define the list elements later: list[i] = count; and I only want to run that part if it's not 0, so only case if I defined other value.

Comment: Run the for-loop with i = 3.

Should 'i' in 'if (i % 2 == 0)' be number instead?

Comment: Not yet... So. 3 will enter the do. It's not even, so entering the else. It becomes (3*3)+1=10, it's below 1.000.000. As the 10th element of the list is 0, it goes to the else -> count++. Now the do loop starts all over again, it will be even, will be multiplied with 2 etc. etc. till the number will be 1.

Comment: Then when is 'number' ever less than 1, to break out of the do-while loop? 'if (list[number] != 0)' will never evaluate to true because you set all the values of the list to zero in the beginning, so the break will never be hit inside of this if block and you are stuck in an infinite loop with number multiplied by 3 (+1) each run and count is increasing each iteration as well.

Comment: See--there's your logic flaw. You're checking i in 'if (i % 2 == 0)'. This value is always the same, never modified. So in the above example.. it is always 3, always odd, and you can never divide it by 2 to eventually be 1 and break out of the do-while loop. You should be checking the number being divisible by 2, instead of the i-iterator.

Comment: OK, yes number, not i.... Sorry mate, I'm so slow today. Now I only have issues with the variable type.

Comment: No problem. Try changing everything back to what you have above except for this change (changing i to number in the check) and see if it works or if you get a different error.

Comment: Perfect with Int32. Thanks again, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help. Good to have a second set of eyes sometimes.